# Named-pipe/ FIFO on USB Mass Storage Gadget to Stream Audio for Car, Docks etc.

Tags: named-pipes, fifo, beagleboneblack, fat32, usb-mass-storage

Many devices (cars, TVs, iPod Docks, AVR receivers etc) have the facility to access class compliant USB Mass Storage Devices and play wav files etc. stored upon them.

I understand I can use a small linux system with appropriate bi-mode USB host/ receiver ports (e.g. a Beagleboard black) to emulate a FAT32 mass storage device (a linux 'gadget') that can be plugged into a car and used as if it were a dumb memory stick -  'g_mass_storage'
http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/file_storage.html

For static files this works fine.  However, I would like to have the beagle board run a bluetooth receiver, decode the stream into PCM and then pipe this into a dummy.wav file that could be read (indefinitely) by the car (ipod Dock etc.)

E.g. 
[Android or iPhone] --> [bluetooth a2dp] --> [beagleboard/ small linux system] --> [PCM audio]* --> [ g_mass_storage].'dummy.wav' --> [car's USB host]

The steps up to the * are  trivial, but I can't work-out how to pipe data into a dummy.wav file as FAT32 doesn't support pipes and yet this is typically the only format supported by cars etc.

It seems something like this is at least conceptually possible:
http://www.dension.com/products/dbu

and 'cubund' on indigogo seems to be following the same principle (sorry can't paste second link as stackexchange won't let me)
I would have bought one if it had got-off the ground!

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Thomas

P.S. the first part of the chain (i.e. the phone via bluetooth) could be any mechanism and isn't particularly interesting.  The challenge is to provide a virtual file that would enable 'streaming' of Google Music/ web radio etc. to devices only capable of reading files from a mass storage device.

Comment: I am interested on this question. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is already on the market for bluetooth. Check on ebay for bluetooth audio receiver. Is a little dongle that you can put in usb port and you may use it like regular usb drive.
Best regards,
Romeo